# editing mysql data (Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0))

Tags: mysql, parameters, sql-update, jbutton

I am trying to make my program able to edit the data from mysql database. this is the code for the jbutton which executes the action, after data has been entered into textfields. I want the user to enter the same 'naziv' column of the row he wants to edit, when editing.

```
JButton btnEdituj = new JButton("Edituj");
    btnEdituj.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/csprogram","root","");
                String query= "UPDATE `maticna ploca` SET `naziv`=value1,`socketi (socket1, socket2)`=value2,`chipset`=value3,`vga port`=value4,`RAM tip i MHz`=value5,`HDD`=value6,`Cijena (KM)`=value7,`Dodatno`=value8 WHERE 'naziv'=value1";              

                PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
                pst.setString(1, textField_1.getText());
                pst.setString(2, textField_2.getText());
                pst.setString(3, textField_3.getText());
                pst.setString(4, textField_4.getText());
                pst.setString(5, textField_5.getText());
                pst.setString(6, textField_6.getText());
                pst.setString(7, textField_7.getText());
                pst.setString(8, textField_8.getText());
            pst.execute();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data updated");
            pst.close();
            }
            catch (Exception d) {
                d.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Try to use `?` instead of `value1` in the update statement as a parameter placeholder.

Comment: Then it says that there is no specified value for parameter 9. I have 9 question marks and only 8 textField.getText()commands. I think I need to write the same parameter placeholder for both cases when I write 'naziv' column. Is that right? That is why I use value1 and not '?'

Comment: You may be able to use named parameters too, but they will likely require the format `:value1`, with a leading colon. Also, you'd have to set those parameters by name too. But I'm not jusre how that works in Java and JDBC, so I cannot provide details on that. If you use the `?` placeholder, each `?` maps to one value, so you'd have to add an extra line that sets the same value again for the last parameter: `pst.setString(9, textField_1.getText());`.

Comment: @GolezTrol there are no errors, the message says that data is updated but it isn't. any ideas? thank you

Comment: The quotes at the WHERE condition is wrong. `'naziv'=value1`. That should be backticks, otherwise you only update if the value of the parameter is `'naziv'`.